# He has cigarettes every day. = He smokes cigarettes every day.?

Tags: meaning

He has cigarettes every day. =  He smokes cigarettes every day.  ??

Do these two sentences have the same meaning?

Thank you very much!

Comment: They do not have the same meaning. We can use 'have' to mean 'consume' about food and drink, e.g. he has meat every day, he has beer every day, but not about cigarettes.

Answer (score 3):

They are pretty much the same, though "smokes" is far better.

I'd probably omit "cigarettes" - since that would be assumed, or irrelevant: "He smokes every day"

"He has cigarettes" does sound odd, but "He has a cigarette every morning" would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

They do not mean the same.

We say 'He smokes cigarettes every day'. (NOT He has cigarettes every day)

We can say-

He has tea everyday. (=He drinks tea everyday.)

He has rice everyday.(=He eats rice everyday.)

(take medicine, breathe air, smoke cigarettes/a cigarette, have tea, have lunch etc.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [very] small possibility of misinterpretation, so just to run you through some of the options:

"I have cigarettes every day" could just mean I keep some in my pocket; even though I stopped smoking months ago, just in case I ever break down, lose my willpower completely, and just have to smoke one.

"I smoke cigarettes every day" is more precise. It's probably a little *too* precise. "I smoke every day", though it could imply cigars, or even that I stand too close to the fireplace until my clothing starts to smoulder… no-one is going to confuse it with that interpretation.

So, they are not identical. I doubt anyone would really care which you used, but the simplest "He smokes every day" would convey the intent quite adequately.

You could go the whole way and just tell us "He's a smoker."
That covers the entire concept in three [and a bit] words.